# Feeding variables into model in R

Tags: r, variables, cox-regression

I am building survival model and my code looks something like this:

```
library('survival')
my.model <- coxhp(Surv(time, event) ~ var_1+var_2+var_3+var_4+var_5, data =df)
```

The problem is that I have too many variables and set of variables is always changing, I wonder if it would be possible to create list of variables and feed it into model. Something like this:

```
 my.var <- c(var_1+var_2+var_3+var_4+var_5)
 my.model <- coxhp(Surv(time, event) ~ my.var, data =df)
```

I found similar post for linear model [linear model solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r), but do not know how adapt it to coxph.

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470403/how-to-model-polynomial-regression-in-r/41470865#41470865

Comment: works similarly for survival models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "." to mean "all variables not used already".  So for your example,

```
my.model <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ ., data = df[,c("time", "event", my.var)])
```

should work.