# In R, when fitting a regression with ordinal predictor variables, how do you suppress one of the polynomial contrast levels?

Tags: r, linear-regression, ordinal

Below is some of the summary data from a mixed model I have run in R (produced by `summary()`):

```
Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -3.295e-01  1.227e-01  3.740e+01  -2.683   0.0108 *  
STANDING.L         8.447e-02  7.091e-02  7.346e+02   1.188   0.2354    
STANDING.Q        -4.624e-03  5.940e-02  7.323e+02  -0.078   0.9380    
STANDING.C         2.899e-03  5.560e-02  7.327e+02   0.052   0.9585    
FIRST.CLASS1       2.643e-02  7.017e-02  7.308e+02   0.376   0.7068    
CAREER.L           1.300e-01  5.917e-02  7.345e+02   2.189   0.0289 *  
CAREER.Q           8.914e-04  7.370e-02  7.295e+02   0.012   0.9904    
GENDER1            9.411e-02  5.892e-02  7.296e+02   1.596   0.1109    
HS.COURSES.L      -3.996e-02  7.819e-02  7.347e+02  -0.510   0.6102    
HS.COURSES.Q       4.977e-02  6.674e-02  7.322e+02   0.745   0.4567    
HS.COURSES.C       2.087e-02  5.735e-02  7.298e+02   0.364   0.7163    
PARENT.LIVE1       5.770e-03  8.434e-02  7.296e+02   0.068   0.9455    
CHILD.SETTING.L    1.241e-01  6.027e-02  7.288e+02   2.057   0.0400 *  
CHILD.SETTING.Q   -4.911e-02  4.879e-02  7.268e+02  -1.006   0.3146    
ES.EXTRA.L         2.702e-02  8.202e-02  7.287e+02   0.329   0.7421    
ES.EXTRA.Q         1.267e-01  7.761e-02  7.274e+02   1.631   0.1032    
ES.EXTRA.C         8.317e-02  7.533e-02  7.287e+02   1.104   0.2701    
TEACH.TAUGHT1      2.475e-01  6.316e-02  7.268e+02   3.918 9.79e-05 ***
SOME1ELSE.TAUGHT1 -1.818e-03  6.116e-02  7.277e+02  -0.030   0.9763
```

Several of my predictor variables are ordinal, as indicated by the Linear (`.L`), Quadratic (`.Q`), and sometimes Cubic (`.C`) terms that are being automatically generated for them. My question is this: How could I re-run this same regression removing, say, the `ES.EXTRA.C` term? In other words, I want to suppress one or more of the automatically-generated polynomial contrasts but potentially keep others. I would have thought `update()` could do this, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I can't share my actual data, but this code will create a few outcomes that are sort of similar and include an illustration of smci's answer below as well:

```
set.seed(151) #Lock in a fixed random structure to these data.
Y.data = sort(round(rnorm(100, 75, 10))) #Some random Y data that are basically the same form as mine.
X.data1 = as.ordered(rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=25)) #Some random X data that are similar in form to mine.

summary(lm(Y.data~X.data1)) #This is what I had been doing, albeit using lmer() instead of lm(). It looks to have been creating the polynomial terms automatically.
summary(lm(Y.data~poly(X.data1, 3))) #Returns an error because X.data1 is not numeric
summary(lm(Y.data~poly(as.numeric(X.data1), 3))) #Now returns a call very similar to the first one, but this time I am in control of which polynomial terms are included.
summary(lm(Y.data~poly(as.numeric(X.data1), 2))) #The cubic term is suppressed now, as desired.
```

As a follow-up, is there a way using `poly()` to get only a certain mixture of polynomial terms? Say, the cubic and fourth power ones only? I have no idea why one would want to do that, but it seems like something worth knowing...

Comment: This is off topic. You may want to try another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Hey @MichaelChernick, thanks for the comment. Can you help me migrate this to a more appropriate site, like StackOverflow perhaps? I don't know how to do it myself...

Comment: You need to post your code. Not a huge dump, just the minimum to reproduce this. In particular we need to see the regression call with the formula.

Comment: Useful reference: [UCLA: "R LIBRARY CONTRAST CODING SYSTEMS FOR CATEGORICAL VARIABLES"](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/). Look at the section about `contr.poly()`

Comment: Hey @smci, sorry, this just got migrated today and I missed that. I am adding a minimal workable example to highlight your points (I can't share my actual data but I can share something faked to look like part of it).

Comment: `lmer()` is for Fixed-Effects Models, if you don't know what that is, don't use it, use plain `lm()`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: after you posted your code:

As I guessed you're building a model using polynomials of ordinal variables:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(STANDING,3) + FIRST.CLASS + poly(CAREER,2) + GENDER +
              poly(HS.COURSES,3) + poly(CHILD.SETTING,2) + poly(ES.EXTRA,3) ...)
```

If you want to prevent cubic terms, use `poly(..., 2)`
If you really want to only have cubic and quartic terms, no quadratic or linear, a hack is to use `I(STANDING^3) + I(STANDING^4)`, although those will be raw polynomials (not orthogonal, centered and scaled like poly() does). I have never seen a need for this, sounds like a very strange request.

See related:

- [How to model polynomial regression in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470403/how-to-model-polynomial-regression-in-r)
- [UCLA: "R library Contrast coding systems for categorical variables"](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)

FOOTNOTE: `lmer()` is for Fixed-Effects Models, if you don't know what that is, don't use it, use plain `lm()`.

Comment: Hello smci, thanks for the answer! See the code I have added to my question--adjust as you see fit to make maximally useful for others. Also, if you have any info to provide about my follow-up question, I would be interested. Also, thanks for the sources. I will take a look (although at least a few of them seem over my head at first glance).

Comment: Hello smci. Yes, I am a mixed-modeler, so I know the distinction between lm() and lmer() quite well. I just realized, as I was writing code for this, that they behaved the same way, so it was irrelevant which I used to demonstrate.